# Why does the event $\{X \leqslant t\}$ is equal to the sample space when $t \geqslant c$ and $X=c$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

This is what is written in my notes.

> Constants are RVs: for $X=c=const$, one has $\{X \leqslant t\} = \begin{cases} \emptyset, t<c \\  \Omega, t \geqslant c\end{cases}$

Why does the event $\{X \leqslant t\}$ is equal to the sample space when $t \geqslant c$ and $X=c$?

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, when $X=c$ and $t\geq c$:
$\{X\leq t\}=\{\omega\in \Omega| X(\omega)\leq t\}=^1=\{\omega\in \Omega| X(\omega)=c\leq t\}=^2=\Omega$
Explanations:
 1. $X(\omega)=c$ for any $\omega$ (this is what is meant by $X=c$).
2. Since $t\geq c$, then $X(\omega)=c\leq t$ for any $\omega$

Comment: +1 The first equality in this explanation is perhaps the most important, because it exposes the abuse of notation inherent in abbreviated expressions like "$X\le t$", which in a more revealing form should be written in the way you have first expanded it.  The "$=^1=$" part doesn't make much sense--precisely how is one supposed to read "$X(\omega)=c\le t$" unambiguously?--and it's a trivial step anyway to move directly through $=^2=$ to the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\newcommand{\F}{\mathscr{F}}(\Omega,\F)$ be a *measurable space*, which means that $\Omega$ is a set and $\F$ is a sigma-field of subsets of $\Omega$. A random variable $X$ is a *measurable* function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, meaning that it must be the case that for every Borel set $B$ in $\mathscr{B}$, where $\mathscr{B}$ is the usual Borel sigma-field of $\mathbb{R}$, the inverse image $X^{-1}(B)=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in B\}$ belongs to $\F$. It is possible to prove that to check that some $X$ is a random variable we don't have to check the inverse image of every Borel set. It is enough to check that sets of the form $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leq t\}$ belong to $\F$, for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Your notes are probably stating that constant functions are real variables. Let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $X(\omega)=c_0$. We have two cases to check: if $t<c_0$, then $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leq t\}=\emptyset$, which belongs to $\F$, by definition. For $t\geq c_0$, $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\leq t\}=\Omega$, which also, by definition, belongs to $\F$ (remember that $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ must belong to *any* sigma-field of subsets of $\Omega$). This concludes the proof that constant functions are random variables.

Notice that we have not introduced a probability measure over $(\Omega,\F)$. Measurability is a property that does not make reference to specific measures over the considered measurable space.